# Access data frame value and store into variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

Code 1:- 
df = pd.DataFrame([{'First':'Bill','Last':'Thompson','AcctNum':'0001','AcctValue':100},
                   {'First':'James','Last':'Winters','AcctNum':'0002','AcctValue':200},
                   {'First':'Anna','Last':'Steele','AcctNum':'0003','AcctValue':300},
                   {'First':'Sean','Last':'Reilly','AcctNum':'0004','AcctValue':400}])
account_value = df.loc[df['AcctNum'] == '0003']['AcctValue'].values[0]
print(account_value)
Output=300

Code 2:- 

df1=pd.DataFrame([{'randomcolumn':'12345'}])
number=df1.loc[:,'randomcolumn']
number=number.values
number.astype(int)
Output=array([12345])
```

I want to store Dataframe (df1) value into integer variable like df account_value? I have tried above code 1 sample example of what I want and code 2 is the sample which i tried but it is giving me array not value.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
number_str=df1.at[0,'randomcolumn']
print(number_str)
# '12345'
```

---

```
number=int(number_str)
print(number)
# 1245
```

Comment: @anserv Thanks !

Comment: I am glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

you can also cast the series into an int using `int()` method.

However this will only work on a single value, if you have more you'll need to return these into an array and access them by an index value or via an iteration.

for your question above simply do :

```
number = int(df1.loc[:,'randomcolumn'])
print(number)
out: 12345
type(number)
out: int
```

Comment: @Skynet Glad we could he of service, if this is your accepted answer please hit the green tick so this can be closed

Comment: the optimal method to select a single value is DataFrame.at

Comment: @ansev agreed but I did mention that in my post